# Select cell in html table generated by foreach

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

please help me with knockout.js code

I try select  element in table by id and change it's css style, but all rows have same id and I can't using function getElementById. How I can do this simple thing ?

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: times">
        <tr>
            <td id=$index() data-bind="click: $root.select.bind($data, $index(), 0)> </td>

        ....

        <td id=$index() data-bind="click: $root.select.bind($data, $index(), 19)> </td>

    <tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Id's should always be unique. Assign the same class to all elements you're interested in and use a bit of jquery:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class_name')
```

EDIT: Good point. I was originally going to suggest using jquery and then remembered this function. If you are using jquery library, you can also try this:

```
$('.class_name').each(function(index) {
    ...do something...
});
```

EDIT: to answer your question, there are a few ways to do this:

```
$('.class_name').attr('id', new_id)
```

or

```
$('.class_name').addClass('class_name')
```

depending on what exactly you're trying to do

Comment: Why do you say use a bit of jquery when your example is native js? the jquery would be $('.class_name')

Comment: How I can write like:
id=jsvariable or class=jsvariable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use such code:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: times">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="attr: {id: $index()}, click: $root.select.bind($data, $index(), 0)></td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
```

Read more about `attr` binding here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html